# Configuring Windows Firewall for Titan FTP Server

Tags: windows-7, ftp, windows-firewall

### Scenario

I run Windows 7 x64 and Titan FTP Server in both Active and Passive mode to share and synchronize data with my laptop and tablet.

### Problem

I have to disable Windows Firewall or otherwise FTP clients won't be able to connect to `PASV` port. With firewall disabled everything works

### Diagnosis

Thanks to Sysinternals's `TCPView` I found that the process listening on port 21 (expecting to listen on new passive ports) is `srxTitan.exe`

I could open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and allow all incoming connections to that process, but... In `C:\Program Files\South River Technologies\Titan FTP Server` I can only find the following files

- srxAdmin.exe
- srxCFG.exe
- srxTray.exe

I can't find `srxTitan.exe` anywhere

### The question

Any advice on telling Windows Firewall that Titan FTP Server is cleared to accept incoming TCP connection on any port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a support engineer at South River Technologies.  I found several articles via google that describe how to setup the windows firewall to allow passive FTP.  For example, http://www.hosting.com/support/windows-server-2008/allow-passive-ftp-access-through-windows-firewall.  Also, srxTitan.exe can be found in C:\windows\system32.  In Titan, you can also limit the passive ports Titan will use - so that you don't have to open everything over 1024.

Comment: +1 for being "official" support. Enabling srxTitan.exe from system32 worked, but the article you linked fails on Windows 7. At least it was my 5-min-ago experience. Again, setting a rule for srxTitan.exe fixes the problem. Thank you

Comment: The link no longer works - you can access it via Wayback machine at: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20130525093606/http://www.hosting.com/support/windows-server-2008/allow-passive-ftp-access-through-windows-firewall

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test if your server is accepting connections on any ports is to host a file with it and attempt to access it from a client on your network.  I know this is a simple answer but it's a simple solution.  Usually when troubleshooting PASV mode, you can at least tell that the connection is being made and then failing when switching to PASV.

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly what I was trying to do. I didn't mention in my question that client request came from LAN (I wouldn't ever use unencrypted FTP on WAN). With Wireshark I realized that the connection to the correct address and port was **not** established (but attempted by client)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is sometime after your question was asked, however I can upon this question while attempting to resolve this issue on a new Web server I was configuring.

The link that [@Jeff](https://superuser.com/users/186721/jeff-swientek) posted,led me in the right direction and I found rules already configured for IIS's FTP Service.  I disabled those rules and created the following rules to access the server using FTP, FTPS and SFTP:

```
FTP  - 20T  - Allow Port  20 using TCP 
FTP  - 21T  - Allow Port  21 using TCP 
FTP  - 21U  - Allow Port  21 using UDP 
FTPS - 989T - Allow port 989 using TCP
FTPS - 990T - Allow port 990 using TCP
FTPS - 990U - Allow port 990 using UDP
SFTP - 22T  - Allow port  22 using TCP
```

Here's the key:

```
FTP - 1024-65535T - Allow passive connections using TCP
```

I also specified a specific program for all the rules:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\srxTitan.exe
```

It looks like they placed srxTitan.exe in the System32 folder.